# JavaScript Canvas - change smoothly rgb

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to change color of a rectangle from 'yellow' to 'blue'. I use for it `fillStyle` with rgb.

```
var 
    canvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas'),
    ctx = document.getElementById('mycanvas').getContext('2d'),
    red = 255,
    blue = 0,
    green = 179,
    inc = 2;

function animate(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(100, 100, 100, 100);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb('+ red +','+ green +','+ blue +')';
    ctx.fill();    
    ctx.closePath();
    red = Math.min(Math.max(red - inc, 36))
    green = Math.max(green, Math.min(182, green + inc));
    blue = Math.max(blue, Math.min(255, blue + inc));

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

animate();
```

The idea was to change valuse of rgb by adding or subtracting variable named inc (equal 2). The problem is that before rectangle reach blue, he gets also other colors (like green for example). This is because the green color will increase by only 3 units, but rest of colors still needs time to get their new values. Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/f2Za8/

Is there any way to make 'green' reach its new value at the same time as the 'red' and 'blue'? How to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```js
var debug = document.querySelector("#debug"),
    canvas = document.querySelector('#mycanvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    red = 255,
    blue = 0,
    green = 179,
    tm = Date.now(),
    inc = 2;
    
function lerp(a, b, n) {
    return (b - a) * n + a;
}
    
function animate() {
    var n = (Date.now() - tm) * 0.001;
    n = Math.max(0, Math.min(1, n));
    
    red = lerp(255, 36, n) | 0;
    green = lerp(179, 182, n) | 0;
    blue = lerp(0, 255, n) | 0;
    
    debug.innerText = `${red} ${green} ${blue}`;
    
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(100, 100, 100, 100);
    ctx.fillStyle = `rgb(${red}, ${green}, ${blue})`;
    ctx.fill();    
    ctx.closePath();
    
    window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
    
animate();
```

```html
<p id="debug"></p>
<canvas id="mycanvas" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: +1, lerping is always simple and effective in handling these kinds of situations.  You might want to take the questioners inc=2 into account in your lerp ;-)

Answer (score 4):

I would use a this function to be flexible about which colors you want to fade into which.

```
function blendColors(r1,g1,b1,r2,g2,b2,balance) {
    var bal = Math.min(Math.max(balance,0),1);
    var nbal = 1-bal;
    return {
            r : Math.floor(r1*nbal + r2*bal),
            g : Math.floor(g1*nbal + g2*bal),
            b : Math.floor(b1*nbal + b2*bal)
           };
}
```

`balance` must be between 0 and 1. So can could increase a variable within the animation loop and call `blendColors()` with this variable as balance argument.

The function returns an object with r,g and b properties. Usage:

```
var blendedColor = blendColors(0,0,255,255,255,0,0.5);
// blendedColor.r contains 127;
// blendedColor.g contains 127;
// blendedColor.b contains 127;
```

I have adapted your example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/f2Za8/7/